# При использовании blueprint в flask на странице появляться дополнительные js скрипты

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

возникла проблема. Если я использую blueprint в flask, то на страницу загружаются какие дебаг js скрипты, которые копируют основной файл и получается один скипт выполняется по 2 раза.

[image]

Внизу мой скрипт, сверху который добавляется. Адрес скрипта: debugger:///{Дополнительная приставка скрипта} reg.js

Вот код основного приложения:

```
from flask import Flask, session
import datetime

from reg.reg import reg

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

app.register_blueprint(reg)

@app.before_request
def change_session_lifetime():
    session.permanent = True
    session.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
```

Сам blueprint:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, json

from reg.models import Reg

reg = Blueprint('registration', __name__)

@reg.route('/reg', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reg_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['pass']

        db = Reg()
        r = db.new_user(password=password, email=email, username=name)

        if r:
            return json.dumps({'status': 'ok'})
        elif not r:
            return json.dumps({'status': 'no'})

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('reg.html')
```

Вот js код этой страницы:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-reg');
form.addEventListener('submit', reg);
var errors = document.getElementById('errors');

function reg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var name = formData.get('name');
    var email = formData.get('email');
    var one_pass = formData.get('one-pass');
    var two_pass = formData.get('two-pass');

    if (one_pass != two_pass) {
        errors.textContent = 'Пароли не совпадают';
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/reg',
            data: {
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'pass': one_pass
            },
            success: function(res) {
                res = JSON.parse(res);
                if (res['status'] == 'no') {
                    errors.textContent = 'Такие данные уже существуют';
                } else {
                    location = '/av';
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Но если допустим я через основное приложение отображу страницу и запущу этот или другой js скрипт, то он выполниться 1 раз. Я пробовал уже запускать приложение с debug=False, все равно эти скрипты добавляются